# Git Merge and Changes, Safe Way to Deal

Tags: git

I am trying to merge a branch into the master.  The branch I built on, called `auths_images` has the changes I want overridden in `master`.  When I merge, I get a whole sleu of errors basically telling me...

```
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I KNOW `auth_images` is up to date with `master`, and has changes that will work with `master`.  How do I get merge to work such that it uses the changes from the branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *add/add* conflict means that since the base, both your current (HEAD) commit on your current branch, and the tip of the other branch, added a file with the same name. Git does not know how to deal with that. You must put the correct combined file into your work-tree and run `git add` on that path name.

If the two files *were* exactly the same, Git would not have a problem.  Git would say to itself: *Gosh, file `somenewfile` is totally new in branch `auth_images` and also totally new in `master`.  But look at that, it's the **same** now in both branch tips!  I can just use either one of them and all will be well!*  So the two files *must* be different.  Git does not know which file to use: the one from the tip of `auth_images`, or the different one from the tip of `master`?  Or perhaps the *right* thing is to combine parts of each!

If you know for sure that exactly one of these two files is the right one, simply extract that one from that commit now:

```
git checkout master -- somenewfile
```

or:

```
git checkout auth_images -- somenewfile
```

Remember, these two are by definition *different:* if they were the same, Git would not have complained.  So be sure that you get the right one.

The act of checking out the right one from the right branch tip will resolve this particular file.  Repeat for every other `add/add` conflict for which some particular file from one of the two branch-tips is correct.  Assuming these were the only problems, your `git status` will now say that all problems are resolved and the merge is ready to commit, and you can now run:

```
git commit
```

to complete the merge.

Comment: Thanks.  I just cleaned up the files after the merge, added them, committed and pushed.